# In Java Socket,DataInputStream doesn't read the Data completely

Tags: java, sockets, networking

So I am trying to send a byte[] array to Server, I used the method DataOutputStream.write(byte[]), it was flushed but never reached the Server side.
So i am trying to send one byte at a time to server and only starting few bytes reach there and the others are lost.

```
Client Side code(ANDROID)

int len=databyte.length;
pr.println(len);
pr.flush();
setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
OutputStream out=soc.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream data=new DataOutputStream(out);

for(int k=0;k<len;k++)
{
data.write(databyte[k]);

}
data.flush();
Log.d("tag", "LEN ;" +databyte.length); //In this case the Length was 1496

Server Side code
int len=Integer.parseInt(first.reader_home.readLine());
InputStream in=first.home_socket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream data=new DataInputStream(in);
System.out.println(len);
img=new byte[len]; //1496

for(int l=0;l<len;l++)
{
img[l]=data.readByte();
System.out.println("1 bit read"+l);
}
System.out.println("READ DATA");


console
1496
1 bit read0
1 bit read1
1 bit read2
1 bit read3
1 bit read4
.
.
1 bit read51
1 bit read52
```

After this Nothing happens

Comment: What is `first.reader_home.readLine()`? NB you can replace the read loop wih `readFully().`

Comment: @EJP first.reader_home is a BufferedReader for the same socket, I tried using readfull() but the server keeps on waiting to receive data even after it is flushed from the client.

Comment: @EJP when i try to close my BufeeredReader that closes the Socket so I am unable to open DataStream on it and read my byte[] array

Comment: You shouldn't even *have* a `BufferedReader,` let alone close it and then try to keep reading from the same socket. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mixed buffered and unbuffered streams on the same socket. You will lose data in the buffered one. You should send the length with `DataOutputStream.writeInt()` or `writeLong(),` and read it with `readInt()` or `readLong().`